# iOS 7 to iOS 8 scrollView with custom icons not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, ios8

I've worked once on an iOS7 app with a lower Horizontal scrollView with custom buttons that let me choose some options. That worked fine, but now while we are giving iOS 8 support, the scroll view appears blank.

iOS 7:
http://postimg.org/image/djv26la4f/

iOS 8:
http://postimg.org/image/4asvwh18f/

I've been trying some possible fixings but I'm stuck in this. Everything is being done programatically, no autolayout.

Do you have any idea of which could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code how you did.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533243/uiscrollview-frame-is-a-different-size-on-ios-8-vs-ios-7

Comment: technical note on uiscrollviews, you have two options: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: If you cant post your code, how are we supposed to fix it??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. It was a problem with the frames as hasan83 said.
After hours of debugging I noticed that a group of frames was with wrong frames despite of using the same code. I fixed it by making distiction between iOS versions.
Thank you for your help!